# How to use perl to replace text between two specific lines

Tags: html, regex, perl

Hi I have a html called 1.html file like this

```
<div class="t_l"></div>
 <some> 
   lines
     of
 codes
 </some>
<div class="t_r"></div>
```

I want to replace the content of that div to another one, which stored in the file called "banner". 
banner file is

```
<other> 
   lines
     of some
 codes
</other>
```

So what I want to get is:

```
<div class="t_l"></div>
 <other> 
   lines
     of some
 codes
 </other>
<div class="t_r"></div>
```

What I come up with using perl is something like this:

```
# Slurp file 1.html into a single string
open(FILE,"1.html") or die "Can't open file: $!";
undef $/;
my $file = <FILE>;
open(BANNER,"banner") or die "Can't open file: $!";
undef $/;
my $banner = <BANNER>;
close BANNER;

# Set strings to find and insert
my $first_line = '<div class="t_l"></div>';
my $second_line = '<div class="t_r"></div>';

$file =~ s/$first_line\n.+?\n$second_line#s/$first_line\n$banner\n$second_line/;

close FILE;

# Write output to output.txt
open(OUTPUT,">1new.html") or die "Can't open file: $!";
print OUTPUT $file;
close OUTPUT;
```

The above code cannot work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use one of the perl HTML parser modules, like `HTML::TokeParser`, for example.

Comment: You really don't want to parse HTML with regular expressions. That way lies madness :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.

The normal regex behavior of `.` is to match any character except a newline. `.+?` in your regex doesn't work for you because there are more newline characters between `$first_line` and `$second_line`.

Using the `/s` modifier tells Perl to let `.` match newline characters, too.

(You also have an extraneous "`#s`" in your expression)

So a working substitution is:

```
$file =~ s/$first_line\n.+?\n$second_line/$first_line\n$banner\n$second_line/s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Go with

```
$file =~ s/($first_line\n)[^\n]+(\n$second_line)/$1$banner$2/;
```

or

```
$file =~ s/(?<=$first_line\n)[^\n]+(?=\n$second_line)/$banner/;
```